# Problem accessing pandas data that is represented with commas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have line as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";", encoding='ISO-8859-1', engine = 'python')
test = str(data['information'])
```

I'm trying to access csv column that contains data in a cell like so: "1000,10500,2500"

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Vastuualue'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erik.ilonen/Desktop/Projekti_csv_data/Toinen_testiohjelma/toinen_datan_kasittely_ohjelma.py", line 12, in <module>
    test = str(dataAlkuperainen['Vastuualue'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'information'
```

Comment: Have you tried printing your `data`? You don't have `'information'` column in it

Comment: Content of your `file.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Your separator is not right.

`sep` should be comma not semicolon, so use `sep=","` instead of `sep=";"`.